# How much hardware is needed to create a microservices demo architecture

Tags: server, architecture, microservices, hardware

I am estimating how much hardware I need to set up a demo microservices architecture (for example: https://github.com/microservices-demo/microservices-demo).

The architecture contains:

- Kubernetes cluster.
- 4 microservices, written either in java, python or golang. With redundancy.
- 1 database per microservice.
- 1 queue or message broker for asynchronous communication, probably Kafka.
- 1 API gateway to connect to the outside.
- 1 Elasticsearch for full-text search of application logs.
- 1 Zipkin for microservices tracing.

Having in mind that it is a demo architecture to extract metric data to create a dataset and even though I intend to use virtualization, docker. How many physical servers will I need ? How much hardware do you think I will need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer to your question, but most of that stuff can be acquired "as a Service" (IaaS or PaaS), so no hardware required.

> I am estimating how much hardware I need to set up a demo microservices architecture

Depends what you want to demo - if you only want to demo functionality, or how the architecture works in terms of the software - then as @quain says, a single PC should work.

> If it is just a pc I think I am far from building a quality dataset.

If you have any specific qualities (such as performance, availability, etc) then you have to quantify those, and use them as inputs to your sizing calculation.  Anyone helping you work out the hardware requirements would also need this.  E.g. are you trying to demo solution behaviour under a specific load?

To even begin doing a hardware sizing exercise you would need at least the following:

- System requirements for every piece of software you'll be using, e.g., Elastic Search.
- Data volumes & types - how many types of record do you deal with (e.g. customers, products, orders, etc) - and for each of those how many do you need for the demo?  1, 100, or 1 million?  The amount of data you have drives storage requirements.  The actions you perform on them also drives computational requirememts and potentially networking requirements.
- Transaction volumes - will the demo be one user clicking around, or will you be using test harnesses to drive millions of requests at the solution?
- Non-Functional requirements / objectives for the demo (performance, etc - if any).

Don't forget:

- Networking - no hardware implications if on a single PC working offline, but a bigger issue if you have multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a code-specific question, so not sure if you should post it here.
Nevertheless, given that there is no specific information about type and performance of services that you are trying to run, I would go with a single PC.
If there is no serious performance needed on the service side, then as a minimal logical configuration I would go with quad core + 16gb ram and ample disk space.
No need for servers, dedicated hardware groups etc.

That is if this is a simple demo and services have limited performance needs. As for upper limits - there are none.

Need of physical servers - in theory only one.
Minikube as kubernetes kluster, docker deployments of services, including broker and db server (same server for all services, just a different db).

For demo purposes this should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The idea is to have an architecture close to a real architecture in production in order to create a dataset of performance metrics. If it is just a pc I think I am far from building a quality dataset. The demo microservices are examples already implemented, but the architecture is not a demo version.

Comment: And, yes, the question is one of software architecture design. About hardware needed to support an architecture, in case this is not the right place, do you know of any that are ?

Comment: I would say to try this question on stack's superuser forum.
As for demo and hardware - without knowing precisely what are you trying to run and what is the performance of those things - it's basically shot in the dark. Everything from my previous could still apply, because containers are still just containers - you would just need to extrapolate. 4 cores and 16gb for db server (sql db x 4 on one srv) minimum or 2-4 cores 12gb per 1-1 sql srv instance - service, 4 core plus 16gb for rabbit / kafka (3-node setup), custom setups for each of microservices. This should be plenty performant.